# Java android retrofit 2 null response

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

This is my response json. I have a sttaus 200 but a response body is null. But a server return a json   :

```
{"user_permissions": {"logout": true}}
```

this is my class :

```
public class Response{

    @SerializedName("user_permissions")
    @Expose
    private UserPermissions userPermissions;

    public void setUserPermissions(UserPermissions userPermissions){
        this.userPermissions = userPermissions;
    }

    public UserPermissions getUserPermissions(){
        return userPermissions;
    }

}

public class UserPermissions{

    @SerializedName("logout")
    @Expose
    private Boolean logout;

    public Boolean getLogout() {
        return logout;
    }

    public void setLogout(Boolean logout) {
        this.logout = logout;
    }

}
```

This is how I call retrofit :

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
    @GET("statuses/configuration")
    Call<Response> getConfigs(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
```

a code I have a 200 but a null response

Comment: Firstly, post some some code where you made the request, preferably from `Retrofit` object creation to enqueuing the `Call`. Secondly you need to verify if the issue is in serialization or getting the response. In order to do that change `Response` to `ResponseBody` as return type of `getConfigs()` and check if in your `onResponse()`, method call `response.body().toString()`'s response. This should now be in string and no conversion should effect the result.

Comment: Can you share your API URL?

Comment: @BelalKhan in soap when I put a request I have a response body

Comment: I am asking for your API URL, then I can actually test your code.

Comment: @Abbas I do not understand what I should to do

Comment: @BelalKhan I can not share this ...

Comment: @kikiKala2 use the **edit** button at the bottom of the post. Make sure to add all the relevant code, as suggested in the above comment. Also add the base URL provided to the `Retrofit` object while creation as suggested by @BelalKhan

Comment: @kikiKala2 then you have to find the solution on your own. Because your code seems fine. And without actual testing, giving solution is very difficult.

Comment: @BelalKhan yes I find I have wrong put output class